# Can I write a copy constructor for an Abstract base class using pointer instead of reference (&)?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, copy-constructor

Was asked this question in IBM ISL interview.
Can I write a copy constructor for an Abstract base class using pointer instead of reference (&)?

I think it can be used. Any comments/suggestions?

```
#include <string>

//abstract base class  
class ABC{
    int a;
    int b;
    char *p;
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    ABC(){};
    ABC(ABC* abc){
        a = abc->a;
        b = abc->b;
        p = new char[strlen(abc->p)+1];
        p = strcpy(p, abc->p);
    }
};

//derived class  
class ConcreteDerivedClass: private ABC
{
public:
    ConcreteDerivedClass(){}
    void f(){}
    ConcreteDerivedClass(ConcreteDerivedClass& obj):ABC(&obj){}
};
```

Comment: why do you need a pointer instead of a reference?

Comment: If i recall right, you *must* use a reference.

Comment: You're perfectly free to write that constructor, but it's not the copy constructor.

Comment: Benjamin, true. But the question is only whether ABC(ABC*) is enough in place of ABC(ABC&)

Answer (score 5):

```
ABC(ABC* abc)
```

This is not copy-constructor.

A copy-constructor must be one of the following forms:

```
ABC(ABC & abc);
ABC(ABC const & abc);  //most common form
ABC(ABC volatile & abc);
ABC(ABC const volatile & abc);
```

The second one is most common. So define a copy-constructor of this form:

```
ABC(ABC const & abc);
```

and then invoke it from the derived copy-constructor as:

```
ConcreteDerivedClass(ConcreteDerivedClass const & obj): ABC( obj)
                                        //^^^^^ make it const
```

Here, `ABC(obj)` calls the base class copy-constructor, passing `obj` as reference.

Note that you're *privately* inhereting from `ABC`.

```
class ConcreteDerivedClass: private ABC
```

*I think* what you need is called `public` inheritance:

```
class ConcreteDerivedClass: public ABC
```

Search for `private` inheritance and `public` inheritance to know the difference between them. You will find numerous topics on this site. :-)

Comment: The first part is correct, then you go into unasked for domains and got lost in the way. There is no reason to advice against private inheritance. It might not be the most common, but it has uses and models a different concept than public inheritance (*implemented in terms of*, rather than *is-a*). Similarly, there are cases (fewer) where you might actually want a copy constructor that takes the argument by non-const reference.

Comment: Private inheritance can also be used if the control on whether the object should be converted to the base class is to be left to the object itself: `class Derived : private Base { ... public: Base* AsBase () { return this; } };` is valid.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Changed the wordings of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, as the compiler will generate a default copy constructor for you. Your example, however, is not wrong. What you call from the derived class just isn't a copy constructor.

Comment: JohnB, Let ABC(ABC*) not a copy constructor. But I think it serves the purpose of copy constructor. Abstract Class can never be instantiated. The only place it is needed is to call from Derived class constructor as shown in the example. From Derived Class Constructor if we just call constructor ABC(ABC*) constructor of base class it would work fine. Are there any cases where we would still be needing real copy constructor for an abstract class ABC(ABC&)

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr390.htm) it must be a reference.